# Select dates from the future or past, if future is not available

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have a simple table for events with a date column. I can easily select
the next *n* events with (assuming *n* = 3):

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE `date` > NOW() ORDER BY `date` LIMIT 3
```

However, not aways there  will be 3 events in the  future. In this case,
I'd like to return the ones available in the future and complete what is
missing with the closest ones to today. E.g., if today is day 12-04, the
following dates marked with a `*` should be selected of the whole list:

```
10-03
20-03
30-03 *
10-04 *
20-04 *
```

While I can easily  check the result of the first query  to find out how
many rows were  returned and build another query to  find the past dates
if necessary, I'm  interested to know if  there is a way  to fetch these
rows in a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple keys in the `order by`.  So:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM events
ORDER BY (date > now()) DESC,  -- future events first
         (CASE WHEN date > now() THEN date END) ASC -- nearest future events first
         date DESC  -- other dates in descending order
LIMIT 3;
```

If your table is large, it is probably faster to get three events from the near future and near past and combine those:

```
select e.*
from ((select e.*
       from events e
       where date > now()
       order by date asc
       limit 3
      ) union all
      (select e.*
       from events e
       where date <= now()
       order by date desc
       limit 3
      )
     ) e
order by date desc
limit 3;
```